# Jquery Fade and Slide issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slide, fade

I made a site using SlideUp and FadeIn as main choice to transition between the content, everything was working well but suddenly stopped working today and i have no idea how to fix it.

I opened the console and don't call any error, i try to remove all scripts but still not working.

Here's the URL from the site ( [Here](http://sistemas.vilavelha.com.br/Newsletter/Ricardo/super-seguros/index.html) )

All errors on the console comes from the iframe

**Edit 1 : Ok it's working now... and the best is i dont touch in the code, just start to work again :)**

Comment: What part exactly isn't working?

Comment: We cannot help you debug your code without seeing it!  If you have saved revisions of your work, you may need to start over from a few days ago.  Your problem is actually quite common with beginning coders.

Comment: what exactly is not working? what's the expected behavior?

Comment: When i click on the banner with the car he change the height of the banner and slideUp the content, slideDown one iframe and shows one sidebar div...

Comment: I do not have any revision of the code, and have more than two weeks I don't changed anything on the code

Comment: the issue is in ".cont-1" and ".cont-2" div... Even when i put te code on console and execute dont slide :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually if you see your console you will some errors, those are `jQuery Migrate Plugin` - Warning Messages. To resolve all these warning have a look at this link:

[jQuery Migrate Plugin - Warning Messages](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/blob/master/warnings.md)

Comment: all errors coming from the iframe migrate are pulling a system from another company so I can not change, and even if I remove the iframe it still does not work

Comment: You cannot access iframe with javascript and plugin is trying to do this which is not possible. Try using [window.postMessage] (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame

Comment: wait a minute, i'm not trying to acess the iframe, I'm just saying that errors are from the iframe.
The real issue is the fadeToggle and slideToggle its not working...
animate, alert, .css, .click its working, fade and slide in the .cont-1 and .cont-2 div is not :/